# Synchronisation algorithms

Tags: algorithm, calendar, synchronization

Are there any good references for synchronisation algorithms?

I'm interested in algorithms that synchronize the following kinds of data between multiple users:

- Calendars
- Documents
- Lists and outlines

I'm not just looking for synchronization of contents of directories *a la* [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync); I am interested in merging the data within individual files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SyncML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncML) is a standard for data synchronization of things normally associated with someone's personal organizer. Nokia and Motorola were both using it heavily a few years ago, but I don't know its current state.

[iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is a calendar synchronization format specification, and [CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) is an implementation of iCalendar atop the WebDAV protocol. Google searches for [iCal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_%28application%29) or iCalendar will likely turn up the iCal application supplied by Apple as part of Mac OS X. Keep looking down the list of results until you see something which looks like a protocol.

Answer (score 14):

There's a high-level and very broad overview of all synchronisation 
algorithms in *[Optimistic Replication](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~ece845/docs/optimistic-data-rep.pdf)* (by Yasushi Saito and Marc Shapiro, [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) format).

Comment: the PDF link links to the wikipedia page for PDF :/

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that looking at any of the open-source source code control applications would give you the right idea - merging changes between files is exactly what they do...

Comment: SCMs are designed for merging lines of ASCII text.  That is not necessarily useful when merging calendars or other structured data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Delta Compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_delta_compression) is what you are looking for.