# Import google calendar into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, google-calendar-api

I'm looking for a way to import a google calendar into a database. All the entries are in the format of `(confirmed) name1, name2, name3 name event` or `?,?,? name event` if not confirmed or `(confirmed) name1, (name2) name event` if name 2 is optional. (there are not always 3 names)

I would like the name and date of the event to go into a database. (name can include all the names and stuff)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are syncing algorithms which would do the work for you as described in this thread:
[Data sync between database and google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015514/data-sync-between-database-and-google-calendar)

The above option requires quite some work and if you need a quick fix, an option could be exporting your google calendar to CSV and then using parser to get its contents in a form that could be transformed into SQL query for inserting it into database.

Comment: I want it to work without any extra operations, as I'm trying to make a cms for our study association and not everybody is good with pc's who has to use it xD

I'll check out the link though