# Synchronize database data with google calendar using google calendar api

Tags: php, mysql, calendar, google-calendar-api

Currently, I'm able to retrieve the events from google calendar for specific calendar e.g. primary calendar. I have referred to this link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#prerequisites for retrieving of events from google calendar.

However, the thing I want is I want when there is a new data/event in the database, it will insert the event that is from database to the google calendar. Similarly, when the data/event is deleted from the database, the same data/event at google calendar will be removed as well. Besides that, when there is a update in event of the database. e.g. changing event title from A to B. therefore, the same event in google calendar should updated as well. In other word, the database data should be synchronize with google calendar.

The screenshot below is the data in database.
[image]

The links below are for get,insert,delete, update events in google calendar.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

Any kind help is greatly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: Check this link: [Data sync between database and google calendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015514/data-sync-between-database-and-google-calendar)

Comment: Thank you, I will look at it.

Answer (score 0):

CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, API_KEY are required for synchronization first.
There is a function that can connect to google calendar as if it prints the data stored in DB. Kelvin, I do not know where you add the data,
If you are adding a data DB on the web screen, add the colum value needed to insert the DB in the function shown below.

Comment: function insertEvent{
  gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
    var event = {
    summary: title
    description: description, // 내용
    start: {
      dateTime: strDate    (startDate)               
    },
    end: {
      dateTime: endDate                   
    },
    iCalUID: Calendar uniq key(I solved this with a sequence.),
      sharing: [{
        "email": (googlecaledar id)
      }]
    };
    var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
      calendarId: email,
      resource: event
    });
    request.execute(function (event) {
    });
  });}